# Convert large data set to rows of comma separated lists

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large amount of data (41k+ rows) that is exported by the company's sales management system, assigning each salesperson to a zip code in the United States. It looks like this (every column has data, but it's mostly irrelevant to me):

```
| Header | Sales Reps  | City   | State  | County | ZIP   | Header | Header |
|--------|-------------|--------|--------|--------|-------|--------|--------|
|        | Sales Rep A |        |        |        | 90001 |        |        |
|        | Sales Rep A |        |        |        | 08801 |        |        |
|        | Sales Rep B |        |        |        | 70001 |        |        |
|        | Sales Rep B |        |        |        | 60001 |        |        |
|        | Sales Rep C |        |        |        | 05501 |        |        |
|        | Sales Rep C |        |        |        | 55001 |        |        |
```

So that, except over 41 thousand times.

I need to be able to take this data and import it into our Wordpress CMS in a format the system can read for a lookup plugin. I'd need it in the following format:

```
| Sales Rep   | ZIPs        | 
|-------------|-------------|
| Sales Rep A | 90001,08801 |
| Sales Rep B | 70001,60001 |
| Sales Rep C | 05501,55001 |
```

We've got about three dozen reps, each with hundreds or thousands of zip codes.

I've tried doing this with vlookups but I hit my wall of knowledge trying to output the results into the comma separated lists I wanted. Is keeping this in Excel even the best way to manage this, or should I be dumping it into something else to work with this many rows of data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already have the unique list of sales reps?  What version of Excel are you using? anything less than Office 365 and you will need vba.

Comment: Export to CVS and use any script language you're familiar with and that's approved at your company? It should be 2-10 lines of code depending on the language and the file format. It doesn't look like something Excel is good at, but occasionally Excel proves me wrong.

Comment: I can suggest you VBA (Macro),, will fix the issue,, just confirm through comments are you comfortable with Macro ?

Comment: @ScottCraner - I could pull it manually (removing duplicates) but if it could be automated that'd be swell.

Comment: @BryanWojciechowski then vba is the way to go.

Comment: @ScottCraner - sorry, I got hung up on the first part of your question and forgot the second. I'm on O365 - is there a way to do this nicely in O365 without vba? I really don't know too much about that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data(in the 1st table) was sorted by RepName, starts at B2 for RepName and F2 for zip code. Also, I assume cell P1 is empty and use column P,Q & R to 'generate' the table 2.

in these

```
P2 ----> =IF(B2=B1,P1&","&F2,F2)
Q2 ----> =IF(B2<>B3,B2,"")
R2 ----> =IF(Q2="","",P2)
```

and drag downwards.

Filter out blanks in Column Q & R , you get your table 2.

Hope it helps.

Btw, for

> should I be dumping it into something else to work with this many rows of data?

If you hit the 32,767 character limit.. it's a yes. Just search for "limit" in your (version of) excel help to verify. ( :

Comment: This looks like it's getting somewhere, but columns Q and R are coming up blank entirely.

Comment: As aforementioned, I'd assumed your "Sales Reps" data is located in column B, "ZIP" data is in column F, which starts at row 2.. Change the formula to suit your Table 1 data location.